# Update existing CoreData records while relaunching the app

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I have a application which uses coreData framework for saving and fetching data for app. Now when user logins in app, a list of cities is fetched from server on pagination basis in chunks of 30 as user scrolls down the table and then these are saved to database in the app, now if user have fetched 3000 records and had saved them to app database, how the older records will update as theres no sync mechanism in the app, as i fetch more records from sever after for e.g. 3000 to 3030.

Also when user logouts out user info is delete on landing screen, which city user has like or user has visited. Now when user login again and i have to mark all his liked cities and visited cities in already saved list.

If anybody please could suggest something, may be i might have done wrong implementation. I'm totally blackout how to approach.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question is unclear. In what way are you trying to update the data, and exactly when is this update supposed to occur?

Comment: Hello @sudo thanks for reply , When we open app again i fetch data from server in chunks of size 0 to 30, so existing records upto 30 items get updated, but i need to update other records too when i scroll down the tableview, but how should i put the logic as there 1000 records shown in table view but i need to update 30 to 60 and 60 to 90 further on, hope i'm clear on this.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you are trying to update records the incorrect way. Updating records is just a matter of changing them in your Core Data store, which I assume you know how to do, and telling your table view (which should have a data source you implemented) to perform updates. It will automatically handle updates as the user scrolls; you don't have to add special logic. This Apple documentation has good examples: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html

Comment: It's also possible that you have a minor bug in your code. Without going back and forth too much here, you should be able to find it by comparing to Apple's examples, or you may even want to rewrite your code based on them. There's also a bit in the beginning about using an NSFetchedResultsController. If you aren't already doing that, I humbly recommend that you do. Good luck!

Comment: @sudo you are correct that scrolling will update the data but it should that frequent as scrolling will update the data again and again in tableView. I normally fetch more  data  on scrollViewDidScroll (next chunk) and update with help of FRC. I have added updation logic in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating on the basis of visible Index  for  updating existing items and update is relevant after 1 hour of updation .Please correct me if i'm wrong in my logic.

Comment: Oh, so you don't want to pull updated records from the server until they're visible. I have tried to do this in the past using `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` like you said, and it has worked pretty well. If you're calling `reloadData` on the table, and it's lagging, you could try `insertRows` instead. And, if possible, you should pull/update more records than are visible so you have some buffer for network latency. There's some discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203016/why-does-my-uitableview-lose-its-fluidity-when-i-scroll-during-an-asynchronous